# How to reverse letters typed into input?

Tags: javascript, input

at the moment whatever you put into my input will appear below what i need is for the result to show the input backwards.
e.g "1234" to be shown "4321"

```
<body>

    <input id="Number">

    <button onclick="Rev()">Reverse</button>

    <p id="paste"></p>

</body>

<script>
function Rev() {
var enter = document.getElementById("Number").value;
document.getElementById("paste").innerHTML = enter;
}
</script>
```

Comment: `enter.split('').reverse().join('')`

Answer (score 1):

Just to show you can use direction: rtl:

```css
input {
  unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
  direction: rtl;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<input value="1234" />
```